# WebStorage - executeSql gives undefined is not a function in for loop

Tags: javascript, web-storage

Here is my code :

Given an object, I'm trying to insert some data in a webStorage db. Problem is that console returns me a "undefined is not a function", and I have no clue why

Here is a snippet of my code

```js
try {
  db = openDatabase("mca", "1.0", "db mca", 200000);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planning_x_material(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, planning_id INTEGER, material_id INTEGER,  material_name TEXT)", []);
  }, onDbError, fillDb);
} catch(e) {
  alert("webstorage error");
}


function callback_planning_material(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    for(var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].material.length; i++) {
        (function (k, i) {
          var planning = obj[k];
          
          var material = planning.material[i];
            
          tx.execuseSql("INSERT INTO planning_x_material(planning_id, material_id, material_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [planning.id, material.id, material.name]); // here console gives me "undefined is not a function" error
        })(k, i);
      }
    }
  }, onDbError);
}

function fillDb() {
  // example object
  var obj = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "name 1",
      material: [
        { id: 1, name: "mat. 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "mat. 2" },
      ]
    },
    
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "name 2",
      material: [
        { id: 3, name: "mat. 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "mat. 4" },
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  
  callback_planning_material(obj);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: you have `tx.execuseSql`, should be `tx.executeSql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `onDbError` not defined
2. `tx` not `tx2`
3. In insert `executeSql` not `execuseSql`

Should work

```
try {
  db = openDatabase("mca", "1.0", "db mca", 200000);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planning_x_material(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, planning_id INTEGER, material_id INTEGER,  material_name TEXT)", []);
  }, onDbError, fillDb);
} catch(e) {
  console.log("webstorage error",e);
}

function onDbError(tx, err){
  console.log('There is error', err);

}


function callback_planning_material(obj) {
  console.log(obj);

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    for(var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].material.length; i++) {
        (function (k, i) {
          var planning = obj[k];

          var material = planning.material[i];

          tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO planning_x_material(planning_id, material_id, material_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [planning.id, material.id, material.name]); // here console gives me "undefined is not a function" error
        })(k, i);
      }
    }
  }, onDbError);
}

function fillDb() {
  // example object
  var obj = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "name 1",
      material: [
        { id: 1, name: "mat. 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "mat. 2" },
      ]
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      name: "name 2",
      material: [
        { id: 3, name: "mat. 3" },
        { id: 4, name: "mat. 4" },
      ]
    }
  ];


  callback_planning_material(obj);
}
```

Comment: `tx2` was a typo converting my file to SO question. onDbError is defined on my file too, just not relevant for this question. Just a stupid typo on `execuTeSql` I guess.. I'm too dumb ! Thanks - Can't reward before 23hrs atm

Answer (score 1):

`tx2` is not defined, should not be `tx` ?

```
tx.execuseSql("INSERT INTO planning_x_material(planning_id, material_id, material_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [planning.id, material.id, material.name]);
```